# Rust Anchor-Spl errors from too many "fallback functions"?

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana

I am trying to build a baseline anchor smart contract, in which I attempted to build a structure with the following (condensed) layout

```
#[program]
pub mod introToAnchor {
    use super::*;
    
    pub fn setData(ctx: UpdateData, data: u64) -> ProgramResult {
    .
    .
    .
    }
    pub fn terminateData(ctx: TerminateData) -> ProgramResult {
    .
    .
    .
    }
    (Function Format repeated)
}
```

yet I get the error `More than one fallback function found`? What is a fallback function, and how do I have too many?

Comment: Can you share reproduce the problem and the code on github maybe

Answer (score 1):

*Jon C's answer should get you going but I can give you the background on that error and fallback functions.*

A not-very-well-documented feature of Anchor is the fallback method to be invoked if the incoming instruction did not match any of the implemented program methods.

The way Anchor decides that a method is *the* fallback one is rather obtuse. Basically, any method that does *not* have the `Context<>` argument is considered a fallback method.

Your original code has two methods that do not have the `Context<>` argument so it sees two fallback methods. A program at any time can only have one fallback method.

Unfortunately, the only reference I can give you for this functionality is this Issue and its corresponding PR. https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/issues/409

Comment: Excellent background, definite trap for new users.

Answer (score 0):

The parser isn't able to generate instruction processors based on the signature of the function, but there's a couple of things that might be going wrong.

1. Instead of returning a `ProgramResult`, you might need to have it return an `anchor_lang::Result`.
2. Try wrapping the data expected in a `Context`.

These two together give:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
#[program]
pub mod introToAnchor {
    use super::*;
    
    pub fn setData(ctx: Context<UpdateData>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
    .
    .
    .
    }
    pub fn terminateData(ctx: Context<TerminateData>) -> Result<()> {
    .
    .
    .
    }
    (Function Format repeated)
}
```

This was lifted from the official tutorial: https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/tutorials/tutorial-1.html#defining-a-program

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Not sure why this worked, but it did:

Error due to pass-by-reference parameter
`pub fn do_something(ctx: &Context<Something>) -> Result<()> {}`
Solved it with pass by value
`pub fn do_something(ctx: Context<Something>) -> Result<()> {}`